# Proving probability theorem $A$ subset of $B$, then $P(A) \leq P(B)$

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the proof for:

If $A \subset B$, then $P(A) \le P(B)$.

I have two versions of the proof and could use help understanding the last step.

FIRST PROOF VERSION:

$P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(B - A)$ : by $P(B-A) = P(B) - P(B \cap A)$

$P(B) = P(A) + P(B-A)$ : by $A = A \cap B$

$P(B) \ge P(A)$ : by Axiom $P(A) \ge 0, P(B-A) \ge 0$

my question how is the last step arrived at and $P(B - A)$ dropped.

SECOND PROOF VERSION:

Similarly, here is another proof from Casella and Berger.  Where does the $0$ come from?  Can I rearrange to inequality to $P(A) \le P(B \cap A^c) = P(B)$?

Thanks

[image: a]
[image: b]

Comment: In your "first proof" I think you meant to say $P(B-A) \ge 0$ by the probability measure properties, not $P(A) \ge 0$.

Comment: @hardmath I think you're right.  I mention it now.  If thats the case, I'm still confused on how the inequality sign is established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With manipulation both the proofs arrive at this form:
[image: proof]

If $P(B \cap A^C) \ge 0$ (by the Axiom $P(A) \ge 0$) then the RHS of the equality implies that $P(B) \ge P(A)$ must be satisfied to satisfy the LHS.  For instance $P(B)=1, P(A)=0$ satisfies, but $P(B)=0, P(A)=1$ does not satisfy because the RHS will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

The [first axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#First_axiom) of probability states that events always have nonnegative probability.

- $P(A) + P(B-A) \ge P(A)$ comes from $P(B-A) \ge 0$.
- $P(B \cap A^c) \ge 0$ is again another direct application of the axiom.

Comment: How are you arriving at or is it a mistake: $P(A) + P(B-A) \ge P(A)$.  Confused by the two $P(A)$ terms.

Comment: Clearly $P(A)=P(A)$ and by definition $P(B\smallsetminus A)\geq 0$.  Therefore $P(A)+P(B\smallsetminus A)\geq P(A)+0$.

Comment: How are you arriving at two $P(A)$ terms?  There is only a single one in both proofs.  The other is $P(B)$.

Comment: @Nick $P(B) = P(A) + P(B - A) \ge P(A) + 0 = P(A)$